# Changing graph range based on specific cell data

Tags: vba, excel, graphing

[See image for what I have going on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDnLP.png)

So the red column will at some point, which is different every day, change from 20 to 50. The start cell up top uses that lookup formula to find when this is. So for this example it is 10/11/16 14:37.  I want to graph the green and blue columns, starting at that cell time and ending at the end time (which is just a max() of the times to get the end time).

I've looked into offset and name manager but I am really confused on those. Either using VBA or something else to change the graph (on a different sheet) to start at whatever that start time is would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:
In the column AL set, in each cell, the value to be defined by the following formula

AL1 `= IF(AI1<50,0,1)`

AL2 and following `= IF(AL1=1,1,IF(AI2<50,0,1))`

Then define each AM to be `AL*AK`, and plot AM.
[image: example]

Comment: Im not sure that would work. That AI columns turns to 50, the goes up to 60, 70, 80, 90 and back to 0. I want to start plotting when it turns to 50. So if I set it to blank when it equals 20 that wouldn't really solve my problem with the data range.

Comment: My bad, I understood you wanted 20 as threshold. If you want to plot when it is 50, change 20 to 50. If you want to have all the cases above 50, change to AB*>49.

Comment: See I don't want to only plot when it is 50, I want it to START plotting at 50. It'll then continue to plot regardless of whatever that value is. So just setting it to 50 or blank won't work.

Comment: Ahh just saw your edit. That might work but it goes from 50 to 90 then hits 0 and does another cycle.... so it would work for the first part of the cycle but not the whole thing. Sorry if this is confusing. XD

Comment: I am not sure I am getting your point. The formula (check the updated version) will hide those values for which the check is below your threshold, no matter the cycle number.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/074ea   Sorry, what I mean is this, it's great for the start of the cycle, but once it goes from 95 to 0, it won't work, because it puts in blanks when I need that data. That's the hard part about this, I don't want to filter out all data = 20 or below, I just want to find in that column when it FIRST switches from 20 to 50, and start plotting data from then until the end.

Comment: Ahh I see, I think that'll work, or I have an idea how to make it work. Thank you very much for the help!